# Second Instance of Form based application does not show a UI

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am facing a strange issue. I have a small Form base GUI application with multiple culture support.

Now when i run this application on my target system, Second instance of Application does not show any GUI.

BUT => I i add a `MessageBox.Show("")` before `showDialog()` call, It works fine everytime.

I am not sure what magic a `MessageBox.Show()` call is doing.

Also application is working fine on build system.

Extra information :

If i comment `System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager , things works fine.

I see second instance is running but not even entering Main as i don't see log which i added.

**A sample code:**

```
   class MyForm : Form
    {
        private Button buttonCancel;
        private Button buttonOK;
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {

        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            var ui = new MyForm();
            var formResult=ui.ShowDialog();
            if (formResult == DialogResult.OK) ;
            {

                // Do something
            }
        }

        }
```

Here is Stack Trace : ( I am good enough to understand this :)

```
0:000> kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0012d4d0 7c90df4a 7c809590 00000002 0012d4fc ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0012d4d4 7c809590 00000002 0012d4fc 00000001 ntdll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0012d570 7e4195f9 00000002 0012d598 00000000 kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x12c
0012d5cc 7752e73e 00000001 0020d1b0 ffffffff user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x13e
0012d5f4 77557297 0020d1b0 ffffffff 0012d620 ole32!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x80
0012d668 79f1a2fd 00000002 ffffffff 00000001 ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0xcf
0012d688 79f1a264 00000000 ffffffff 00000001 mscorwks!NT5WaitRoutine+0x51
0012d6f4 79f1a1c8 00000001 0020d1b0 00000000 mscorwks!MsgWaitHelper+0xa5
0012d714 79fcccd0 00000001 0020d1b0 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x28
0012d798 79fccd65 00000001 0020d1b0 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c
0012d7e8 79fccee9 00000001 0020d1b0 00000000 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40
0012d844 79e7549a ffffffff 00000001 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::WaitEx+0xf7
0012d858 79fd774d ffffffff 00000001 00000000 mscorwks!CLREvent::Wait+0x17
0012d8e4 79f016f0 001593a0 ffffffff 001593a0 mscorwks!AwareLock::EnterEpilog+0x8c
0012d900 79f01674 4ea81039 0012d9c0 001593a0 mscorwks!AwareLock::Enter+0x61
0012d9a0 00ce3a15 013a44f4 00000000 00000000 mscorwks!JIT_MonEnterWorker_Portable+0xb3
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0012d9f0 79e80838 00361efe 0012da24 4e8438a1 0xce3a15
0012da2c 79e71b4c 001f4778 00231290 0012dabc mscorwks!PreStubWorker+0x141
0012da3c 79e8968e 00000000 00000000 0012dbec mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x33
0012dabc 79e89e8b 00000000 00000000 0012dbec mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa3
```

Comment: How do you start the second instance of the application?

Comment: How does the `ShowDialog` call apply? Can you post some code?

Comment: It also work  once if i change Display Language of System.

Comment: Are the resource assemblies being loaded by the second application? You can check this if you attach with the debugger of Visual Studio. Or use Process Explorer from SysInternals.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **[STAThred]** attribute to your Main method.

```
[STAThread]  
public static void Main()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is already present (sorry i did not put in sample code)